# Cycles Plane With Equal Shading On Both Sides

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shadows, hdri

I made some grass, but with the lighting I am using one side is dark because there is no light shining on it, so I want it to have no shading, but the problem is I still want it to change colors with the hdri, just have equal shading on both sides.

Comment: You can start from combining *Principled* & *Translucent* shaders with `Add` or `Mix` shader.  For `Mix` use *Backface* socket of *Geometry* node. Optionally you can play with *Normal edit* modifier which is commonly used for plants

Comment: could you include a picture?

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/yR3yZZI